# Element UI Table - Add Percentage as Width

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

We can add `width` to an element ui table column as such:

```
<el-table-column
  prop="city"
  label="City"
  width="120">
</el-table-column>
```

However, it only produces a pixel value.

Is there any solution how to make it use a percentage value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oddly enough, for `<el-table-column>`, `width` is in pixels, but `min-width` is distributed proportionally between the columns.  Here's how a table might span 100% of the clientWidth with columns that are 33% and 67%:

```
<el-table :data="[{a:1,b:2}]" style="width: 100%" ref="table">
    <el-table-column :min-width="33" prop="a" label="A"></el-table-column>
    <el-table-column :min-width="67" prop="b" label="B"></el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/rn05vbsL/2/

Comment: You absolute legend. Been working with Element for years and didn't know this!